# applications similar to cloud browse

Tags: java, ios

Does anyone know of any applications similar to Cloud Browse that would be open source? I'm trying to develop a personal iOS app (not for sale) that will let me use Java applets on an iPad. Or if you have any other idea on how else I can accomplish this, I'd be interested.

Comment: I don't think this is the correct site to ask this question

Comment: I'm trying to develop an application to run a Java applet inside using iOS...how is Stack Overflow not the correct site to ask a development question?

Comment: Ah.. I read your question wrong. I thought you were just looking for an app similar to Cloud Browse, not looking to make one yourself.